# Angular 4 ng-repeat implementation

Tags: list, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to implement a very basic ng-repeat directive for a Ionic 3 project using Angular 4. I simply don't understand why this code is not returnig anything. I guess the numerous of the Ionic and Angular documentation are confusing me....
Any idea?

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public item = {} ;
public itemsList = [
    {"name":"Mark", "position":"CEO"},
    {"name":"David", "position":"Developer"}
];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item of itemsList">
        <h3> name: {{item.name}}</h3>
        <p> position: {{item.position}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You forgot 'let' in ng-repeat which should by *ngFor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemsList">
        <h3> name: {{item.name}}</h3>
        <h3> name: {{item.position}}</h3>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Working code is https://gitlab.com/ugur.ayan/temp-ionic/

Comment: If it is a Angular 2-4 project

Comment: Thanks Dr. Geek but I believe Ionic 3 is using Angular 4.
When using *ngFor, the console returns an error like "Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'"

Comment: It is working well. I create a working version for you https://gitlab.com/ugur.ayan/temp-ionic/ and 
>> ts code is https://gitlab.com/ugur.ayan/temp-ionic/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts 
>> html code is the same

Comment: I forgot to add the "let" before "item". Thank you very much Dr. Geek

Comment: You are welcome but I think you are new in angular. Don't forget that ng-something such as ng-repeat, ng-if ,ng-controller and so forth represents angular1.x . In above angular 2 versions these directives change as ngFor, ngIf, etc... Have a nice coding...